# Using Paypal GetTransaction Details not able to get details

Tags: java, paypal

I did **TransactionSearch** using the **Permissions** and then **GetTransactionDetails**. But i am getting paypal response as :

```
INFO [NVPAPICaller] - ADDRESSOWNER=PayPal&ADDRESSSTATUS=None&TIMESTAMP=2012%2d05%2d04T06%3a57%3a56Z&CORRELATIONID=a25eb3e65a642&ACK=Failure&VERSION=51%2e0&BUILD=2860716&L_ERRORCODE0=10004&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid%20transaction%20type&L_LONGMESSAGE0=You%20can%20not%20get%20the%20details%20for%20this%20type%20of%20transaction&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error&PENDINGREASON=None&REASONCODE=None Ack : 200  Elapsed Time : 2,213 ms
```

Its showing that  I cant get the details of this transaction. Where can I get the list of transactions which are possible to access through **GetTransactionDetails**. and for these transactions how to get details

Answer (score 0):

GetTransactionDetails does not return details for all transaction types. In particular, Transfers do not have transaction details. What type of transaction are you trying to use?